# Why is my SVG showing in Chrome, but not in other browsers?

Tags: html, css, firefox, svg, microsoft-edge

I am trying to show an SVG with a bit of CSS in browsers like Edge and Firefox. In Chrome it is working as expected, but not in any other browsers. I have singled out the problem in the CodePen below. Don't mind the messy styling (in the original version there is a different font etc).

The problem is that the SVG is simply not shown at all in other browsers. When I inspect the element it does show the code needed, but nothing is there on the front-end. I am not very experienced with SVG.

I have tried: Adding a `viewbox` (though I am not sure if I did this correctly) and changing the size of the box around it. Neither did help.

[CodePen](https://codepen.io/Remith/pen/OGaqBy)

```css
svg {
    font-size: 260px;
}

.colortext .anim-shape:nth-child(1) {
    fill: white;
}

.colortext .anim-shape:nth-child(2) {
    fill: #19b5b3;
}

section.portfolio-page {
    background-color: #252627;
    min-height: calc(100vh - 120px)
}
```

```html
<section class="portfolio-page">
    <svg>
        <!-- Clippath  with text -->
        <clipPath id="cp-text">
            <text text-anchor="middle" x="50%" y="30%" dy=".38em" class="text--line">
                RT
            </text>
        </clipPath>
        <!-- Group with clippath for text-->
        <g clip-path="url(#cp-text)" class="colortext">
            <!-- Animated shapes inside text -->
            <rect width="100%" class="anim-shape"></rect>
            <rect width="23%" class="anim-shape blue-logo"></rect>
        </g>
    </svg>
</section>
```

Comment: No height attributes on the rect elements. You'll need to use SMIL or javascript if you want to animate a rect height in Firefox.

Comment: But in this example I am not animating anything (though I would like to in the future). This does not explain why it is not working now, right? And do you need to animate rects with javascript for edge and explorer as well?

Comment: So just provide a height attribute on the rect elements. Yes to the edge/explorer question though you can use SMIL there too via [fakesmile](https://github.com/FakeSmile/FakeSmile)

Comment: @RobertLongson I just tried adding height to the rect elements, it did not work unfortunately.

Comment: It sure seemed to work for me when I did it.

Comment: @Remi, I added the height attribute without any unit like height="150" and it looks like it can help to solve the issue for other browsers. You can try to test it on your side and let us know about the result.